# Activating a virtual environment

Tags: django

In the Course "Python and Django Full Stack Web Developer Bootcamp" lecture 115 Django set-up, I progressed till `activate myDjangoEnv`.

I've already created myDjangoEnv and try now to activate it. But, I can't.

in the lecture after activation it reads

```
(MyDjangoEnv) C:\Users\Marcial>
```

but in my case, after running `activate myDjangoEnv`, I get

```
PS  C:\Users\myusername>
```

How can I activate myDjangoEnv?

Answer (score 0):

windows:

```
cd environment
cd Scripts
activate.bat
cd ..
cd ..
```

Linux:

```
source environment/bin/activate
```

replace environment with myDjangoEnv.

Comment: thank you. but, I still struggle to get rid of that PS before C:\Users\myusername
I need to have a clear C:\Users\myusername     in order to to activate myDjangoEnv

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have created a Django project inside a directory "main" with the name "mydangoproject" and a virtual environment "env" to support it. Then to activate the virtual env use the following command based on your OS.

Windows:

```
C:\main>env\Scripts\activate<br />
(env) C:\main>
```

Linux:

```
source environment/bin/activate
```